# Javascript: intercept property setting when property name is not known

Tags: javascript, properties, local-storage, interceptor

Using JS, I would like to capture new properties creation on `window.localStorage` no matter the way this is done. The properties names are random as they are storageItems keys. So, how can i intercept statements like `localStorage.propX = 'smthg'` or `localStorage['propY'] = 'smthgelse'`? Note that I am not aware of the `propX`, `propY` in advance.

It seems that `Proxy` cannot do the job because I want to intercept references to the original `window.localStorage` not references to the proxy. The reason is that the calls I would like to intercept is not my code.

Also the `Object.defineProperty` method cannot do the job because it requires the property name which I am not able to know.

Comment: You can create a proxy for `localStorage` and assign that to `window.localStorage` though?

Comment: Can't you use a `Proxy` and then assign that back to `window.localStorage`? Eg, `window.localStorage = new Proxy(/*...*/)`. This way any code that accesses `localStorage` will instead receive your proxy object. Of course this only works if you can ensure that this replacement happens _before_ the code which accesses `localStorage` runs.

Comment: You usually don't set properties on `localStorage`, but use the method `setItem()` to set items. You could replace that method with your own implementation.

Comment: @OskarGrosser I tried this. Javascript does not allow to set localStorage. Only getter is permitted on this property of window object.

Comment: @OskarGrosser your are correct and I have done this on `setItem` but I would like to cover any scenario.

Comment: @CRice it seems that being a property of `window`, setter is not permitted on `localStorage` itself. Is there anyway to bypass this?

Comment: Can't be done without redefining `window.localStorage`, sorry.

Comment: The exact message when assigning the proxy to localStorage is ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property localStorage of #<Window> which has only a getter```